# am getting error after i created amazon coginto in android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Hi am doing a project which syncs the data to amazon coginto and its working fine, and successfully signed apk too.

Now the problem is am getting error after debug

"Unrecognized suffix for the AWS http client class name b"

Comment: Can you please provide stack trace?

Answer (score 8):

You probably turn on Proguard and have class name obfuscated. The SDK does reflection based on the class name. Without it some feature may not work correctly. Please see the instruction https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/Proguard.md for configuration.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error with these rules.

Answer (score 2):

Girdhar G. Patel's solution works for version 1 of the aws sdk and the source for the answer is here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-proguard-with-the-aws-sdk-for-android/

If you're using version two you'll need a different proguard configuration to get it working:
(source: https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-aws-2.1.5.pro)

```
# These options are the minimal options for a functioning application
# using Proguard and the AWS SDK 2.1.5 for Android

-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.**               { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.org.apache.commons.logging.** { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.QueueUrlHandler  { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.javax.xml.transform.sax.*     { public *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.javax.xml.stream.**           { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.**.model.*Exception* { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.internal.**                   { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.**                             { *; }
-keep class org.joda.time.tz.Provider                   { *; }
-keep class org.joda.time.tz.NameProvider               { *; }
-keepattributes Signature,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.amazonaws.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.events.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.impl.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.conn.scheme.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.org.joda.convert.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.**

#SDK split into multiple jars so certain classes may be referenced but not used
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.services.s3.**
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.services.sqs.**

-dontnote com.amazonaws.services.sqs.QueueUrlHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

I exactly had same issue. I was getting this issue only when I run my release apk on kitkat and JellyBean devices. I have added following rules in proguard file and it worked.

```
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.**               { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.QueueUrlHandler  { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.javax.xml.transform.sax.*     { public *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.javax.xml.stream.**           { *; }
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.**.model.*Exception* { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.**                             { *; }
-keepattributes Signature,*Annotation*

-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.events.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.impl.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.conn.scheme.**

-dontwarn com.amazonaws.util.json.**

-keepnames class com.amazonaws.**
-keepnames class com.amazon.**

-keep class com.amazonaws.services.**.*Handler

-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**

-dontwarn org.apache.http.**

-dontwarn com.amazonaws.http.**
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.metrics.**
```